# How to set up Jest for CSS modules in Gatsby 3?

Tags: javascript, css, jestjs, gatsby, css-modules

In Gatsby 3 `import styles from './styles.module.css'` syntax is no longer supported and has been replaced with `import * as styles from './styles.module.css'`.

Unfortunately, using the new syntax doesn't work with the suggested Jest setup, i.e. using `identity-obj-proxy` for CSS modules - accessing any property on `styles` object returns `undefined` rather than the property name.

It does work correctly when I'm using named imports, e.g. `import { wrapper } from './styles.module.css'`, but as I'm migrating a rather large app to Gatsby 3, I'd prefer to initially use `import * as styles ...` syntax.

Is there any other recommended way to set up Jest that would work with both `import * as styles from ...` and `import { wrapper} from ...`?

Answer (score 1):

There's a [solution](https://github.com/keyz/identity-obj-proxy/issues/8) provided in one of the open issues for `identity-object-proxy`. It allows you to use `import * as styles ...` syntax to satisfy Gatsby by modifying Jest's configuration.

Create a mock to modify `identity-object-proxy` for style files:

```
// .jest/__mocks__/identity-object-proxy-esm.js

module.exports = new Proxy(
  {},
  {
    get: function getter(target, key) {
      if (key === '__esModule') {
        // True instead of false to pretend we're an ES module.
        return true;
      }
      return key;
    }
  }
);
```

And update jest config to use the mock:

```
// jest.config.js 

module.exports = {
  ...
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp|svg)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    '\\.(css|scss)$': '<rootDir>/.jest/__mocks__/identity-obj-proxy-esm.js'
  }
};
```